# Accessing MonetDBLite outside R

Tags: r, monetdb, monetdblite

I created a big database using MonetDBLite in R and now I want to access the database outside R (e.g., with a general database GUI).

Is there a way to do this?  I do not want to replicate the data as I still want to access it through R. I do not need to access the database concurrently from R and a SQL GUI but I want to switch between the two as needed.

Comment: There are all sorts of ways this could be done. Have you tried? If you have tried to implement this and are having trouble (e.g. error messages, lost data, etc.), please post your code and we will try to help you. We do not implement new features for free.

Comment: +1.  downvoters please explain your downvote.  this is a reasonable question for anyone familiar with `MonetDBLite`.  @flippke you might be better off creating the server as an external database and then connecting through R with `MonetDBLite::MonetDB.R()` instead of `MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite()`.  for more details, see http://www.inside-r.org/node/425876

Comment: I did start the MonetDB daemon (in Linux).  Based on my understanding of the documentation the daemon starts for a dbfarm and the farm contains the database.   I already had a database (embedded) and I did not find a documented way to create a dbfarm that could contain an existing database (I created the dbfarm in the parent folder of my existing database).  The farm could not see the database, and I tried creating a database within the farm as a reference of config files for the farm but this did not work. I do not have any code beyond shell commands to create and start a dbfarm.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, thanks!  In hind sight I should have created a regular MonetDB instead of an embedded one.  I am new to MonetDB and wanted to run some analysis in R but ended up running too many SQL statements from R and thought it should be more efficient (from a coding perspective) to do it from an SQL gui instead of R.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyDamico, somehow the link with the details you posted takes me to the MRAN home page - that's not right - right?

Comment: look at google's cached version?